# Getting the unique string(such as an IP address) of a PC unit when connecting to the UDP Server

Tags: java, udp, udpclient

How to get the unique string(such as an IP address) of a PC unit when connecting to the server.

I can get the IP address of a pc unit if the unit sends a msg to the server.

However, I want to know how to get the unique string such as IP address of a pc unit just by running `java UDPClient` which connects to the server and not needing to send a msg to get the IP address.

Comment: as far as I know, when client trys to connect to a server, it requires a "handshake" which is basically sending and receiving some data(msg)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If the client doesn't send a message to the server the server doesn't even know the client exists. UDP doesn't have permanent connections, just individual messages going back and forth.

Comment: then how can i send a message from a client to server then server to all clients like an 'All Chat'. I've tried multicastsocket but it won't work to other pc units.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Multicast udp works well if all nodes are in the same network segment. Otherwise you can have the clients send a message to tell the server they want to join the chat. The server maintains a list of who has joined and copies every message to every client individually.